# More advanced tag question

Tags: question-tags

> 1. It's not like Einstein knew everything, did he?

or

> 2. It's not like Einstein knew everything, didn't he?

What's the correct variant and why?

Comment: Neither. **It's not** like Einstein knew everything, **is it**?

Comment: Have you considered "is it?"

Comment: I considered the possibility that I'm not allowed to question the second verb, but are you guys completely sure it's like that? I can only work with the leftmost verb?

Comment: @Enirsa BillJ is considered to be one of the top grammarians on the site. If he says it, I believe it.

Comment: Alright, thank you!

Comment: It's not a leftmost verb issue. It's whatever verb you are contrasting.

Comment: So, if the options in your post change a different verb from the one you wanted to ask about, be aware that you could also say ***Einstein didn't know everything, did he?***

Comment: It seems to be a case of the speaker treating initial _It's not like_ as if it were an adverbial phrase, which would make _know_ the main verb, and taggable. Since there's a negative in there, that complicates things, to say the least. The point is that the speaker believes that Einstein didn't know everything, whatever that means.

Comment: It's part of that misconception "If you are so smart why aren't you rich?"